# psd file to textures

Tags: materials

I'm very new to Blender so this may be a very stupid question. Anyway, I'm trying to make a special effect for a video. It should happen in a shopping mall, so I bought a pre-made shopping mall from cgtrader website. It includes a blender file, but that doesn't have any textures in place. It also included layered photoshop file, which looks like very nicely rendered view. It says in the original text "The file has all lightning setup and texturing ;multi layer phososhop PSD file included" Also there's a folder of some textures. So my question is: how do I get these textures into my Blender file? Can it somehow automatically link them? It's a huge file of a shopping mall so making all the textures by hand seems like huge work. (which I tried to avoid by bying the readymade file..;-) Thanks for any help!!

Comment: If the materials on the objects reference the psd file as a texture, they will show up inside blender.

Comment: Most likely the blend file included has the textures already, but the links to the original paths are different (most likely the creator used absolute paths, instead of relative). use the File>External Data>Make all paths relative. In any case, since you paid for it you should contact the seller and find out.

Comment: Ok, thank you for help!  Didn't work that way though unfortunately. I contacted the seller.. I hope they can give me some info..